# Ubuntu 23.04 6.2.0-36 AND 35 totally hosed now. Only have recovery mode?

Tags: kernel, 23.04

How to get out of this mess. Grub only shows two kernels. Nothing seems to work.

Recovery mode is giving me no connctions.

Tryin https://serverfault.com/questions/21475/starting-network-connection-from-ubuntu-recovery

But instructions are wrong/vague/do not work yet for me.

The usual error is ... end kernel panic - not syncing: vfs: unable to mount root fs on unkown-block

This happens with nearly every kernel update recently and I fix by doing some reboot into old kernel and manually installing some kernel headers.

This time I have no reboot options ... trying to get out of this.

Comment: Have managed to get internet in recovery.

Comment: ifconfig enpxxx up
dhclient enpxxx

Comment: ok this got me running after recovery mode: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic

Comment: That's great you fixed your issue!  Please go ahead and write your answer below and you can then accept it as the correct answer.  This may help others that might be experiencing the same issue.  Have an awesome day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to boot in recovery mode then enable wifi then run the install command to fix the headers.

Likely it will be some device enp. Type `ifconfig` to see the full list and guess which one is wifi. Then do something like this

```
ifconfig enpxxx up dhclient enpxxx
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic
```